# Ajax call is not working, "404 not found error" showing in Yii Framework

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I've crated simple ajax call function in yii framwork but its not working, its giving 404 not found error message in console.  
 
Ajax function in main.php page

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'actionSendSms',
          type: 'GET',
          data: {user_id :array_id[i]},
          success: function(response){                                    
            console.log(response);                                 
          }
        });
```

"actionSendSms" in controller:

```
 public function actionSendSms(){
         return '1';   
        }
```

accessRules() function in controller:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','actionSendSms'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','actionSendSms'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete','actionSendSms'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

The error message from console is:

```
GET http://www.domain.com/admin/index.php/sendSms/actionSendSms?user_id=32 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use   the call without the "action" prefix

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'sendSms',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {user_id :array_id[i]},
      success: function(response){                                    
        console.log(response);                                 
      }
    });
```

accessRules() function in controller:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','sendSms'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','sendSms'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete','sendSms'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

try echo for response

```
public function actionSendSms(){
     echo '1';   
  }
```

Comment: The 404 problem got solved. But its not returning value '1'. Its returning blank value. Is something missing?